# Set a public variable of bean in spring without using a setter

Tags: java, spring

I read on a few websites that with Spring its possible to do setter based Dependency Injection without having to create a setter for the injected variable it. Would nicely tidy up the code. I read this [on another](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-el-hello-world-example/) site and also here on stackoverflow.

I've tried it but in my case it does not work. I'm using  3.2.0.RELEASE. I'm getting the following error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DI_without_setter' defined in class path resource [SpringBeans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'url' of bean class [net.comsys.springpropstest.DiWithoutSetter]: Bean property 'url' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

**my Java test code**

package net.xxx.springpropstest;

```
public class DiWithoutSetter {
private String url;
}
```

I've just added it to my main code. Not displayed here. I don't even use DiWithoutSetter in the main code.

**SpringBeans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="DI_without_setter" class="net.xxx.springpropstest.DiWithoutSetter">
    <property name="url" value="jan" />
</bean>
```

If someone could shed some light on his issue that would be appreciated. Is it possible to set the value of a (public) variable in a Spring bean without using a setter method?

Comment: You can do injection without using setters. But then its not setter based injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that (you need a setter), and that tutorial appears to be wrong (note in the example source zip, the classes have getters and setters).

Either add a setter or `@Inject` the field implicitly using autowiring.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to annotate the field with `@Autowired` and enable component scanning for this injection to work without a setter method.